# How does WEKA IBK (KNN) algorithm lead with non-normalized attributes?

Tags: normalization, weka, knn

I have a large dataset for two classes with different attributes scales (some attributes from 5 to 10, others from 0 to 100, for example). I know if I use directly a kNN algorithm that difference will invalidate the analysis and I need to normalize the attributes.

Some classifiers on WEKA appear to do that normalization, like the RBF or SMO, but I need to use other classifiers, firstly IBK classifier (KNN).

Does weka lead with it in some way? How can I incorporate a normalization process in KNN classification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For maximal freedom (ability to transform your attributes in the way that suits you best: standardization, min-max normalization, etc.), you can normalize your attributes using for instance MATLAB (or Python...).
For this, you have to load/store your dataset in form of a matrix (where the columns correspond to your attributes, while the rows to your training instances/examples, which is typically for a CSV file). Then you can easily manipulate with the columns, e.g. loop over each columns and normalize it.

Finally, you may feed the new dataset with normalized features into Weka.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Preprocess" Panel there is an unsupervised attribute filter called "Normalize".